# How to update my UIViewController to current orientation when use pushViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

i have use this code but it is Private API ,apple also reject!

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

if i rotate my device in Landscape then open my Application it will present as Portrait mode, i need to rotate my device to another orientation then it will update.

how to update it to correct orientation when call UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the follow code at your UIViewController class:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

if u need to update orientation at runtime then u have to return other constant

`return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);`

Comment: thanks Yakov, this code will call when the device have change orientation, it can answer my problem, that is when push my View it will present incorrect orientation. so if i force it with setOrientation: it will be reject by apple.

Comment: So... Also you would try to add 'Initial interface orientation' property into info.plist. for ex: you can set value 'Landscape (right home button)' or 'Portrait (top home button)'.